# Java chars vs C++ chars from file

Tags: java, string, file-io, encoding, ascii

I need to read chararacters from a file that are written by a C++ process.
The characters are for sure in the range of ASCII but since the Java char is a 16 bit and a C++ char is 8 bit, what would be the best way to read the file?

I only know that the C++ process writes chars in ascii range as follows: file<

Comment: Read Java `byte`s, each one will hold one (ASCII) character.

Comment: The internal representation of char has nothing to do with it --- classes like InputStream, Reader, etc. will care about that. Important is only that you let the system know how the file is encoded.

Comment: @Ingo:How do I do that?I only know that the C++ process writes chars in ascii range as follows: `file<<theChar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to specify the file encoding. You'll can use:

```
File myFile = new File("file.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f),"ascii"));
```

Comment: It is better to use UTF-8 as encoding, though. This subsumes ascii, and the C++ program might change in the furture, or differnt data sources are explored.

Comment: @Ingo:Would that be `UTF-8` or `UTF8`?

Comment: @Jim The name of the character set in java is "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Try using Guavas [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) Class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File("filename"),
                    Charsets.UTF_8);
            //get characters from lines

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
        }
    }
```

You could also try out the other Read methods in that class see if they serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

When you read  an ascii file in Java it will correctly be represented as 16 bit chars in java. When you write a java char to a text file it will written to disk as 8 bit ASCII characters as long as you stay within the ascii character range.

Code to read a file line by line:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    // Do something with the line
    line = br.readLine();
}
```